# A good way to find a limit of decay curve-like integral?

Tags: calculus

For $n=0, 1, 2, 3,\cdots,\;$ let $\;a_n = \displaystyle \int^{n\pi}_{0} x e^{-x} |\sin x| dx.$

and calculate $ \displaystyle a =\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n.\;$  I tried using the reductive formula,

$$ c_n = \pi e^{-(n-1)\pi} \int^\pi_0 e^{-x} \sin x dx + e^{-\pi} c_{n-1}$$

where $c_n$ denotes $a_{n}-a_{n-1}$ to get

$$a = \frac{\pi e^{\pi}}{e^{2\pi} - 2e^{\pi} + 1} \frac{e^{-\pi}+1}{2} + \frac{1}{1-e^{-\pi}} \frac{\pi e^{-\pi} + e^{-\pi} + 1}{2}$$

but the expression is to complex; I wondered whether there are better methods thatn this. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried using piecewise integration directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done a nice work and arrived at the good result

$$a = \frac{\pi e^{\pi}}{e^{2\pi} - 2e^{\pi} + 1} \frac{e^{-\pi}+1}{2} + \frac{1}{1-e^{-\pi}} \frac{\pi e^{-\pi} + e^{-\pi} + 1}{2}$$ Now, use the fact that
$$e^{\pi}=\cosh(\pi)+\sinh(\pi)$$
$$e^{-\pi}=\cosh(\pi)-\sinh(\pi)$$ If I am not mistaken
$$a=\frac{1}{4} (\pi +\sinh (\pi )) \,\text{csch}^2\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$$